# Jenkins "Execute Shell Script" vars needed in post-build action specifically in send email body?

Tags: jenkins

So I set up some vars in Execute Shell Script build action which I would like to use in my post-build action like send email's body. Is this possible without using any plugins? If not possible without plugins what are the plugins that I should use? Thanks very much,

Answer (score 9):

Not possible without plugins because:

- **Execute Shell Script** and **Post-build actions** are run in separate environment sessions, so anything that had been set in the former is not available in the latter.

What you need is the **[EnvInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin)**.

- In your **Execute Shell Script** step, instead of setting an environment variable, write the key-value pair to file, for example `myvar=somevalue`.
- Add another build step, called **Inject environment variables for your job**. Give it the location of the file with the key-value pair.
- Now that variable is available as an environment variable for the rest of the job run (including other build steps and post-build steps).

Comment: **In your Execute Shell Script step, instead of setting an environment variable, write the key-value pair to file, for example myvar=somevalue.** could you expand on this? This is precisely what I need to do but what steps did you use to write to a file, where should that file live, what kind of file, etc?

Comment: @partydog depends on your shell. If on linux, you can simply write `echo myvar=somevalue > vars_to_inject.txt`. Provided you didn't change directories in your "Execute Shell Scrip"t step, it will default to `${WORKSPACE}/vars_to_inject.txt` location. This is a plain text file, with 1 key-value pair per line. In the "Inject environment variables for your job" step, specify the location of that file

Answer (score -1):

You can set any  environment variable using the "**Generate environment variables from script"** by using:
echo "MY_VAR=$SOME_VAR"

Then this variable is available through the entire jenkins job process. at any shell/ batch command and even at the mail or any other plugin.

Comment: Nope. Didn't work for me. Did you mean 'export' instead of 'echo'? Either way didn't work.