# Jenkins:How could I use the variables set by the build scripts at email notification?

Tags: jenkins

When jenkins build pass, an email will send to all members

I want to use the variables set by the build scripts at my email content

The Editable Email Notification seems not to support my own variables

Comment: What do you mean by _my own variables_? You've got a job setting some environment variables?

Comment: Yes! For example: The jenkins job is to download some kinds of image to different place. And after mission complete, an email will send to me: $IMAGE_NAME has been download at $IMAGE_PLACE

Comment: Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995648/jenkins-execute-shell-script-vars-needed-in-post-build-action-specifically-in) - this should solve your problem.